# Highchart is not occupying entire div in Shiny app

Tags: highcharts, shiny, shinyapps, r-highcharter

I have below `Shiny-app`

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(shinycustomloader)

Data1 = structure(list(x = c(39, 15, 21, 71, 39, 34, -47, 67, 5, 1, -41, 
                             41, 6, 52, 84, 10, 67, -53, 15, 21, 51), y = c(0, -7, 75, 100, -67, 
                            52, 100, 100, -200, 0, -100, 28, 19, 100, 35, 39, 24, -73, 100, 
                            29, 81), z = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
                                           "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u")), row.names = c(NA, 
                            -21L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style = "height: 1000px; width: 80%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4)",
      div(style = "height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0",
          highchartOutput("Result",  width = "100%", height = "100%") %>% withLoader(type = "html", loader = "loader6")
        ))
)

server = function(input, output) {

output$Result = 
        renderHighchart({

            HighCharts_Plot =
                hchart(Data1, "scatter", hcaes(x, y)) %>%
                    hc_chart(plotBorderWidth = 1, plotBorderColor = '#b4b4b4') %>%
                    hc_annotations(list(labelOptions = list(y = 35, x = 0, backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', borderColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"),
                                        labels = list(list(point = list(x = (max(abs(range(Data1$x))) + 0)/2, y = 0, xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0),
                                                            style = list(color = '#6f6f6f', fontSize = 8),
                                                            useHTML = TRUE,
                                                            text = paste("<span style = '", "padding: 3px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4)", "'>AAA  AAA  AAA  AAA  AAA  </span>", sep = ""))))) %>%
                    hc_tooltip(outside = TRUE) 
            HighCharts_Plot

        })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you see here that the `highchart` is not occupying entire `div` when height is defined as `percentage` instead of `px`. However setting height as `%` is often required for `responsive web-page design`.

Is there any way to work with % declaration of height properly?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the loader, the `div` of class `shiny-loader-output-container` should have `style = "height :100%"`. Remove the loader if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts charts are 400px height by default. You can set `chart.height: '100%'`
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height

```
hc_chart(plotBorderWidth = 1, plotBorderColor = '#b4b4b4', height = '100%') %>%
```

The chart will get 100% of the parent container which is `shiny-loader-output-container` but, for some reason, this `shiny-loader-output-container` container doesn't get 100% height of the parent.

Comment: And for a width declaration? I f we want the width be the whole page?

Comment: Doesn't "width = '100%'" work?

Comment: It worked with ```hc_size(width = 1750)``` .